# How to enable the column of jquery datatable depends on login user accessability

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

How  to enable the column of jquery datatable depends on login user accessability ,If login user is admin then only last column should show/hidden, How to do in datatable function. Here is my code:

```
    var $table=$('#example').dataTable
                ( {
                    "bFilter": false,           
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        'type': 'POST',
                        'url': 'getResult.php',
                        'data': {
                                    formName:'afscpMcn',
                                    action:'search',
                                    mcn_no: document.getElementById('mcn_no').value,
                                    cust_nm:document.getElementById('cust_name').value,
                                    emp_id: document.getElementById('employ_name').value
                                }
                                },
                   "columnDefs": [ 
                                   { 
                                     "aTargets":[4],  // this your column of action
                                     "mData": null, 

                                     "bSortable": false,
                                     "mRender": function(data, type, full)
                                     {
                                      mcnDel=String(full[0]+full[1]);
                                      var rowId= full[0];
                                      return "<td><a href='javascript: void(0);'    id='deleteOrd' onclick='updateMcnTab(\""+rowId+"\");' ><img src=images/edit-icon.png></a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</a><a href='javascript: void(0);'  onclick='getResultsMcn(\"delete\",\""+mcnDel+"\");' ><img src=images/delete.png></a></a></td>";   // replace this with button 
                                     }  
                                    }
                                ]
                 });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "enable"? Hidden, not sortable ..?

Comment: if admin login last  column should show otherwise hide

Comment: You could return a value from `GetResult` which determines whether or not to show the column, then just do a check for it in 'mRender'. Alternatively you could populate a hidden field on the page and use `fnSetColumnVis` to set visibility.